# Site wide hreflang

Tags: html, seo, multilingual

So I'm using nodaddy builder and can't upload a site map, and can only add site wide header tags, not page specific. My site has two languages and is very small:

- English:

  - `example.com` (`example.com/home.html`)
  - `example.com/about.html`
  - `example.html/contact.html`
- Chinese:

  - `example.com/homecn.html`
  - `example.com/aboutcn.html`
  - `example.com/contactcn.html`

Can I just add site wide `hreflang` tags pointing Chinese to `homecn.html` and English and default to `/` root? I think I'd be making one of [Google’s common `hreflang` mistakes](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en):

> Missing confirmation links: If page A links to page B, page B must link back to page A. If this is not the case for all pages that use hreflang annotations, those annotations may be ignored or not interpreted correctly.

The pages do have links to each other though (`contact.html` links to `contactcn.html` and vice versa), so I'm unsure if putting static `hreflang` tags across my site will work. Or in my simple case is it not even necessary to have these tags?

Comment: Can you give us an example? Can you create one folder for the sites in English and another one for the sites in Chinese?

Comment: U can't do folders in godaddy website builder... im switiching to wordpress